# cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: java, unix, ubuntu, command-line, jar

I ran a java executable file using the following command

```
java -cp .;aa/bb/cc/dd/Main.jar aa.bb.cc.dd.Main
```

where aa.bb.cc.dd is the package that has all the .java, .class, and Main.jar files
and this package is inside the src folder from where I am running this command.
I am getting an error

```
cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: Using a semicolon begins a new shell command, so the system is trying to treat the jar as a native executable rather than run it on the jvm.

Answer (score 1):

Semi-colon in bash is used to separate commands. So in your case

```
java -cp .;aa/bb/cc/dd/Main.jar aa.bb.cc.dd.Main
```

`java -cp .` and `aa/bb/cc/dd/Main.jar aa.bb.cc.dd.Main` are considered as two separate commands and executed in sequence.

The issue can be fixed by changing the ";" to ":".

The path delimiter for java class path is ":" and not ";".